# Как при нажатии на кнопку вызвать меню

Tags: java, android, android-menu

Вроде как на многих телефонах нет кнопки меню, а панель лепить не хочу, хочу вызывать меню при нажатии на `ImageButton`. Как под неё переделать эту команду:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: То, о чем вы спрашиваете, называется "всплывающее меню" (popup menu). https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вызовите метод у активити: `openOptionsMenu()`